# What happens to protected method of a super class in base class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

I have a `A` class in `package1` and `B` is in `package2` which inherits `A`. `A` contains method `m1` which is `protected`. Now my doubt is when I create an object of `B` in another class `C` which is also `package2`, the object of `B` is unable to access method `m1` why? Below is my code

```
package com.package1;

public class A {

    protected void m1(){
        System.out.println("I'm protectd method of A");
    }
}


package com.package2;

import com.package1.A;

public class B extends A {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B b = new B();
        b.m1();          // b object able to access m1

    }

}


package com.package2;

public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hi hello");
        B b = new B();
        b.m1(); //The method m1() from the type A is not visible

    }

}
```

Do protected method of super class become private in subclass?

Comment: Protected methods can only be accessed by the class which extends the class where the method lies. You cannot create a object of sub-class and invoke super-class protected method. However you can invoke a method of subclass using a object which in turn invokes super-class protected method.

Comment: @Darshan Lila if you see my code in class B i created subclass object and invoked m1() which belongs to super clas

Comment: If you override the method `m1()` in class `B` then it will be visible to `C` as well i.e. in class `B` `@Override protected void m1() { super.m1(); }`

Comment: @DarshanLila: "...can only be accessed by the [extending] class."  This is not quite correct.  The `protected` access modifier provides access that is in every way the same as default (or package-private) access with the addition that subclasses have access to the member as well.

Comment: @DarshanLila: yes if i override it will be accessible but if i don't override what is the status of m1() in class B i sthat still protected or private? As per private access modifier it will be available with in the class itself. Do m1() become private in B?

Comment: Visibility is still protected, only that protected methods are visible to package classes and the inheriting classes only, class C qualifies as none of them for A

Comment: @rock: access to `protected` members is the same as default or package-private access.  So, classes in your package will be able to access the member, but those outside will not (excepting classes that extend your class with the `protected` member).

Comment: @DarshanLila - i placed Class c also in same package as in B

Comment: Remember until unless B defines method `m1()`, the method can not be considered to be defined in the package, It is just visible to class `B` but `B` does not own it

Answer (score 8):

From [JLS 6.6.2. Details on protected Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2)

> A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object.
>
> Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.

**Means** The `protected` modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

From [Java Doc Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)
[image]

---

So you can access method `m1` from class `B` even its not on same package because it subclass of `A`.
But you can't access method `m1` from class `C` because neither its in same package as `A` nor its subclass of `A`.

So for accessing this method you can make method `m1` public or move your class `C` into same package as class `A`

Comment: class c also in same package, what happens to method m1 in B immediately after inheriting A?

Comment: @rock you can't access method like `b.m1()` in package2, you can access it only within subclass of A if its outside package1.

Comment: See given link in answer for more details.

Comment: @ Sumit Singh does m1() become private in class B?

Comment: No like private is a keyword mean no one can access it, same protected is also keyword which mean no on can access it from outside package or outside subclass.

Answer (score 0):

the main thing the docs tells is the protected fields can only accessed from the package within or  from the sublcass in another package. But it does not tell anything  by the object anywhere else . Any object should invoke it from the package within or from the subclass in another package.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!