# Protected data member(Method) is not accessible to child class into same package

Tags: java, package, protected, access-modifiers

I am having troubles related to protected access modifier.

```
package pack1;
public class A{
    protected void m1(){
        System.out.println("Protected method");
    }
}
```

```
package pack2;
import pack1.A;
class B extends A{
}
```

```
class C extends B{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        B b = new C();

        b.m1();// Error: method m1() is protected access  modifier in package pack 2
    }
}
```

Why is B class' method not accessible even though its present in same package pack 2 in which B class exit? And protected access modifier is accessable in same package so why this error occured?

Comment: `".... even though its present in same package?"` -- please justify this, since class B and C are defined in package pack2, while class A defined in pack1.

Comment: class B and class c in same package pack2 so when i am trying to access b class method so why its not accessible.

Comment: Yes I know A class method is not accessible but Class A method is inherit to class B, Now i am using m1() method of class B which is in same package

Comment: package pack2;

import pack1.A;

public class B extends A {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  B b = new B();
  b.m1();
 }
 
}

class C extends B{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  B b = new B();
  b.m1();
 }
} 
if we run B class so it will fine but when we run C class it says CE-The method m1() from the type A is not visible. Why it says type A, after inherit it will be the method of B.

Comment: OK, I see what you're getting at. I'm sorry for my confusion.

Comment: Same question with a valid answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30207940/522444

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to protected method of a super class in base class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207940/what-happens-to-protected-method-of-a-super-class-in-base-class-in-java)